# Вывод даных из последней записи

Tags: mysql

Идет запись данных из апи разных сайтов в БД. Обновление данных каждые n минут, новые данные записываются в БД. 
Юзеру нужно выводить только последнюю запись, но как это сделать ?  Или просто делать перезапись используя UPDATE и WHERE id=1 ?

Comment: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` или `SELECT max(id) FROM Table` пробовали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать выборку, отсортированную по ID в обратном порядке и взять только 1 запись

```
SELECT * FROM blablabla
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```